# Unflatten array to Tree without parent id but with level

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm a bit stuck with something implying recursion. I am receiving data 
 from an API. It looks like this:

```js
const input = [
  { id: 'a', level: 0 },
  { id: 'b', level: 1 },
  { id: 'c', level: 1 },
  { id: 'd', level: 2 },
  { id: 'e', level: 1 },
  { id: 'f', level: 0 },
];
```

and I need something like

```js
const out = [
  { id: 'a', nodes: [
    { id: 'b', nodes: [] },
    { id: 'c', nodes: [
      { id: 'd', nodes: [] },
    ] },
    { id: 'e', nodes: [] },
  ] },
  { id: 'f', nodes: [] },
];
```

How would you achieve that in an elegant way such as `out = f(input)` ?

I feel we can do a recursive nest method through a reduce but I did not manage to get it right :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is `c` not a child of `b` ?

Comment: @ClydeLobo they have the same level

Comment: Constructing a tree from your input doesn't make much sense. As the parent --> child information is missing. For eg a, f is on level 0 and b, c and e are on level 1 so b, c, e could be children of a or f. Similarly d could be the child of b, c, or e.  How are you able to determine who is the child of what?

Comment: @Ajit, the order is one information as well, beside the level. the actual nodes is assigned to the given level in order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a helper array for the levels with the latest array/nodes property from the object.

```js
const
    input = [{ id: 'a', level: 0 }, { id: 'b', level: 1 }, { id: 'c', level: 1 }, { id: 'd', level: 2 }, { id: 'e', level: 1 }, { id: 'f', level: 0 }],
    result = [],
    levels = [result];
    
input.forEach(({ id, level }) =>
    levels[level].push({ id, nodes: levels[level + 1] = [] })
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I read it 10 times to see where you reinitialise sublevels, and where you set it. Empressive!

Comment: @nina-scholtz woot ! I had never thought of that "mutate while assigning". That it pretty clever and I love it! I'llwait a bit to see other responses , but i'll  give you the credit!

Answer (score 0):

You may try out like,

```js
function makeObject(id){
  return { id: id, nodes:[] };
}

function addObjectToNodes(array, id, node){
  array.map(a => {
    if(a.id === id)
      a.nodes.push(node);
  });
}

const nodes = [];

nodes.push(makeObject('a'));
nodes.push(makeObject('f'));

addObjectToNodes(nodes, 'a', makeObject('b'));
addObjectToNodes(nodes, 'a', makeObject('c'));
addObjectToNodes(nodes, 'a', makeObject('d'));
addObjectToNodes(nodes, 'a', makeObject('e'));

console.log(nodes);
```

Comment: Seems that you missed correlation between `level` property and expected structure...